# How to find and replace string between two tags using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

If we have a text like this:

> [SYS 1]Page 1 from 2:[/SYS]
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard ...
>
> [SYS 2]Page 2 from 2:[/SYS]
>
> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
>   electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

How should I keep only text between [SYS] and [/SYS] tags? like this:

> Page 1 from 2:
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard ...
>
> Page 2 from 2:
>
> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
>   electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

I think the following regex would find the text inside two tags without attributes:

```
/\[SYS\](.+?)\[\/SYS\]/
```

But how should I replace the entire element with the inner text (or any other string) for that tag?

Comment: Your regex looks close (and good), but I would use this: `/\[SYS \d+\](.*?)\[\/SYS\]/` ... find on this, and replace with the first capture group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
\[SYS[^]]*\](.+?)\[/SYS\]
```

And replace with `$1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dI4dB6/1).

---

In `PHP`:

```
$regex = '~\[SYS[^]]*\](.+?)\[/SYS\]~';
$string = preg_replace($regex, '$1', $your_original_string);
```

See a demo for the complete code on [**ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/hExi1d).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace like so:

```
$re = "/\\[\\/?SYS(?:\\s\\d+)?\\]/";
$str = "[SYS 1]Page 1 from 2:[/SYS]";
echo preg_replace($re, "", $str)
```

Comment: It will remove "[SYS n]" and "[/SYS]" only? what if I want to replace the text between these tags later?

Comment: @asDca21 then use `$re = "/\\[SYS \\d+\\](.*?)\\[\\/SYS\\]/"; `

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: You have **far** more backslashes then needed here :) Also, consider using another delimiter, e.g. `~`.

Comment: @Jan which backslash would you remove?

Comment: See answer above :)